# Batteries and amps in parralel

Tags: voltage

So, i am about to buy a brushless motor a ESC and a 18650 batteries for my arduino.

The batteries "specs" is 3.7v and 20a, if i would to put 2 and more in parallel would i get 7.4v 20a or 7.4v 40a?

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Arduino.

Comment: where would i then post it?

Comment: The electronics stackexchange. Also what is that battery specification? 3.7V is the loaded battery voltage, but 20A? Maximum continuously deliverable current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In parallel you'd get 3.7V 40A

What I think you mean is in **series**. That way you get 7.4V 20A.

Answer (score 0):

Series connection of battery adds voltage not current but parallel connection keeps the voltage same. Current may be increased with some condition.  One things should be remembered 20 a current is huge it is not required by arduino. May be for some welding device it needs that current which can be controlled by high current mosfet